# How to route to your dashboard after being logged in when using MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an View folder and has login.cshtml, i want after a user logged in to route to dashboard that i created. Which route page shall a user need to go to, useful example will be enough. In another words i want when user is logged in, must redirect them to my below Index.cshmtl(dashboard for EventManagement List). Please help mates, need routing to flow from page to page. The register to login works fine, its just my login must route to my dashboard for users to see event list.

```
// RouteConfig.cs file
  routes.MapRoute(
                name:"Dashboard",
                url:"{dashboard}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new {controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index"}
             );

// Views/Dashboard/Index.cshtml


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EventManagement List";
}
<hr/>
<hr/>
<hr/>
<h2>EventManagement List</h2>
<table id="EventManagementTable" class="ui celled table" style="width:100%">
    @*Semantic UI*@
    @*<table id="EventManagementTable" class="ui celled table">*@
    @*Bootstrap*@
    @*<table id="EventManagementTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">*@

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>TrainingID</th>
            <th>TrainingType</th>
            <th>TrainingDescription</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Venue</th>
            <th>Facilitator</th>
            <th>WhoAttend</th>
            <th>RSVP</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>TrainingID</th>
            <th>TrainingType</th>
            <th>TrainingDescription</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Venue</th>
            <th>Facilitator</th>
            <th>WhoAttend</th>
            <th>RSVP</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

</table>


<!--Normal DataTables-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.20/datatables.min.css" />

<!---JQuery ThemeRoller-->
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--Semantic UI-->
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.semanticui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@section scripts{

    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.semanticui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

    <script>

     $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#EventManagementTable").DataTable(
                {
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/EventManagement/GetList",
                        "type": "POST",
                        "datatype": "json"
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "TrainingID" },
                        { "data": "TrainingType" },
                        { "data": "TrainingDescription" },
                        { "data": "Price" },
                        { "data": "Facilitator" },
                        { "data": "WhoAttend" },
                        {"data":"RSVP"}
                    ],
                    "serverSide": "true",
                    "order": [0, "asc"],
                    "processing": "true",
                    "language": {
                        "processing":"processing...... please wait"
                    }

                });

     });


    </script>


    }

// Views/Account/Login.cshtml

@model ContentManagementSystem.Models.LoginViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login in";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-info" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register") if you don't have a local account.
                </p>
            }
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section id="socialLoginForm">
            @Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginListPartial", new { Action = "ExternalLogin", ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

-Must this first be created on RouteConfig.cs
e.g defaults: new{controller = "Account", action = "Index"}
```

Comment: whats in the method public virtual ActionResult Index(... on the account controller, you would return the dashboard view from there once login has been validated ?

Comment: @level_zebra give me a default example.